# How to invoke webservices in 3 different machines parallelly using thread from a web application

Tags: asp.net

In my web application I have to call webservices from 3 different machines parallelly. How can I do this using thread in asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
namespace WebApplication1
{
      public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
      {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }
            protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               DCIService1.DCIServiceClient client1 = new    DCIService1.DCIServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IDCIService11");
               client1.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               client1.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               client1.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               client1.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               Label2.Text = client1.Execution(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
               DCIService.DCIServiceClient client = new DCIService.DCIServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IDCIService1");
               client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               client.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               Label2.Text += client.Execution(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
               DCIService2.DCIServiceClient client2 = new DCIService2.DCIServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IDCIService12");
               client2.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               client2.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               client2.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               client2.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
               Label2.Text += client2.Execution(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
           }

           protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
                Label2.Text = "";
           }
}}
```

here DCIService,DCIService1 and DCIService2 are service references

Comment: with this piece of code it's not too clear what do you want to achieve but I think you can manage this using [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is what I was looking for